# Abstract Classes - Super Constructor (Java)

Tags: java, class, abstract

I have a really simple question:

Let's say I have an abstract class which represents a person in a bar.

```
public class Person {
    protected String firstName;
    protected String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And I also have 2 classes that extend Person, let's say a class for bartenders and a class for customers.

In the class for customers, I also want an int representing his age as a field. In the bartender class, we don't.

Also, for the customer class, I want a method isAdult().

```
public class Bartender extends Person {
    public Bartender(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

public class Customer extends Person {
private int age;    

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I now have 2 questions:

1) This doesn't work as I get the message "Implicit super constructor Passenger() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor".
What does this exactly mean?
2) For the method isAdult(), I feel like the best way to do it is to implement it in the abstract class Person like this:

```
public abstract boolean isAdult();
```

And then implement it for Bartenders returning always true and for Customers checking their age.

Another way is implementing it from the class Person directly like this:

```
public boolean isAdult() {
    return (this instanceof Bartender || age > 18);
}
```

Would that work and which way would be better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Person has a defined parameter using constructor and no default parameterless constructor. Since a child class's super constructor must always be called in the child constructor, and since Person has no default constructor, you must **explicitly** call it in the child constructor:

```
public Bartender(String firstName, String lastName) {
    super(firstName, lastName);

    // don't do this:
    // this.firstName = firstName;
    // this.lastName = lastName;
}
```

and

```
public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
    super(firstName, lastName);
    this.age = age;
}
```

Regarding `isAdult()`, you could just have this method in the Customer class and not have it in Bartender. Alternatively if the super must have this method, you could throw an exception if someone calls it on a Bartender, since it should not be called that way.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to 1: Java actually always calls the constructor of the superclass. For example:

```
class Super{
}

class Base extends Super{
     public Base(){
          //super() will always be called implicitly if a defaultconstructor is provided by Super

          //do something else
     }
}
```

This is done, since the structure of a baseclass consists of the structure of the baseclass and the one of the superclass. Without initializing the structure of the superclass by calling a constructor of the superclass, errors might occure. Since Person doesn't provide a defaultconstructor, but needs to be initialized anyways, you have to explicitly call the superconstructor with the two parameters.

Answer 2:
It Both would work fine, but i (and everyone else aswell i hope) will highly recommend implementing it separately in the derived classes to keep everything extensible, clean, readable and for thousands of other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, notice something: when you create a class, it's automatically created for you a default constructor of that class. If you create another constructor, you **must** so create the default one ("default" here is without parameters) by yourself, because Java thinks you know what you are doing now. So, just add it at the `Person` class:

```
public Person(){}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, see Hovercraft Full Of Eels's answer; for your second question, I think you should just give `Person` an "age" property (every person has an age) and the logical `isAdult` implementation. If `Bartender` is really a `Person`, it should have an age. Therefore, I don't think you should be able to assume `Bartender` is an adult in the first place. In whatever logic you have that calls `Person#isAdult`, have it assume `true` in the case that the `Person` is a `Bartender`.

Answer (score 0):

Second part of your question:
Make isAdult() abstract in the superclass, provide specific implementations in children classes. If it turns out that several of the children classes have a similar implementation, then you can consider putting that implementation in the parent class and override as appropriate.

Parent classes should never know about their children classes, so getting the parent to check for instanceof children is to be avoided.